# Another boost error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

On this code I get the enourmous error

```
static void ParseTheCommandLine(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int count;
int seqNumber;

namespace po = boost::program_options;

std::string appName = boost::filesystem::basename(argv[0]);

po::options_description desc("Generic options");
desc.add_options()
("version,v", "print version string")
("help", "produce help message")
("sequence-number", po::value<int>(&seqNumber)->default_value(0), "sequence number")
("pem-file", po::value< vector<string> >(), "pem file")
;

po::positional_options_description p;
p.add("pem-file", -1);

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::command_line_parser(argc, argv).
          options(desc).positional(p).run(), vm);
po::notify(vm);

if (vm.count("pem file"))
{
    cout << "Pem files are: "
         << vm["pem-file"].as< vector<string> >() << "\n";
}

cout << "Sequence number is " << seqNumber << "\n";

exit(1);
```

../../../FIXMarketDataCommandLineParameters/FIXMarketDataCommandLineParameters.hpp|98|error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::operator<< [with _Traits = std::char_traits](((std::basic_ostream >&)(& std::cout)), ((const char*)"Pem files are: ")) << ((const boost::program_options::variable_value*)vm.boost::program_options::variables_map::operator[](((const std::string&)(& std::basic_string, std::allocator >(((const char*)"pem-file"), ((const std::allocator&)((const std::allocator*)(& std::allocator()))))))))->boost::program_options::variable_value::as with T = std::vector, std::allocator >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > >’|

Comment: You really should show the declaration of `vm`...

Comment: probably a similar error you would get from cout<< vector<string>();

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remember to **ask a question**.

Answer (score 3):

Vectors don't implement `ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &)`.

You should probably do:

```
cout << "Pem files are: ";
for (auto & x : vm["pem-file"].as< vector<string> >())
    cout << x << "\n";
```

Comment: It is part of the tutorial http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#id2607140

Comment: @user1676605: boost tutorials may have bugs.

Comment: gotcha thanks. I solved it by template < class T >
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& v)
{
    os << "[";
    for (typename std::vector<T>::const_iterator ii = v.begin(); ii != v.end(); ++ii)
    {
        os << " " << *ii;
    }
    os << "]";
    return os;
}